# Delete hidden files in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, delete-file

Does anyone know how to delete all files in a directory with Ruby. My script works well when there are no hidden files but when there are (i.e .svn files) I cannot delete them and Ruby raises the Errno::ENOTEMPTY error. 
How do I do that ?

Comment: Ack - can't post an answer without getting a server error. Take a look  at http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/130295

Comment: And the documentation for `rm_rf`: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/FileUtils.html#M004336

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specifically want to get rid of your svn files, here's a script that will do it without harming the rest of your files:

```
require 'fileutils'
directories = Dir.glob(File.join('**','.svn'))
directories.each do |dir|
    FileUtils.rm_rf dir
end
```

Just run the script in your base svn directory and that's all there is to it (if you're on windows with the asp.net hack, just change .svn to _svn).

Regardless, look up Dir.glob; it should help you in your quest.

Comment: There is a typo at the script, a dot after svn at line 2. It should be:
directories = Dir.glob(File.join('**','.svn'))
I tested it on both linux and windows and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

.svn isn't a file, it's a directory.

Check out [remove_dir](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/FileUtils.html#M004344) in FileUtils.

Answer (score 1):

It probably has nothing to do with the fact, that .svn is hidden. The error suggest, that you are trying to delete a non empty directory. You need to delete all files within the directory before you can delete the directory.

Comment: I think the problem is that the file *is* hidden, so it's not coming up when he lists the files in the directory using whatever method he's using so he doesn't delete them.

Comment: He says it raises Errno::ENOTEMPTY so he probably just needs rm_rf from FileUtils.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can delete (hiden) directory using  `FileUtils.remove_dir path`.

I happend to just write a script to delete all the .svn file in the directory recursively. Hope it helps.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'fileutils'
def svnC dir

    d = Dir.new(dir)
    d.each do |f|
            next if f.eql?(".") or f.eql?("..")
            #if f is directory , call svnC on it
            path = dir + "/" + "#{f}"
            if File.stat(path).directory?
                    if  f.eql?(".svn")
                            FileUtils.remove_dir path
                    else
                            svnC path
                    end
            end
      end

 end

 svnC FileUtils.pwd
```

Comment: I seem to remember you can achieve the same thing with Subversion by doing an svn export to the same folder you have the checkout.

Answer (score -1):

As @evan said you can do

```
require 'fileutils'
Dir.glob('**/.svn').each {|dir| FileUtils.rm_rf(dir) }
```

or you can make it a one liner and just execute it from the command line

```
ruby -e "require 'fileutils'; Dir.glob('**/.svn').each {|dir| FileUtils.rm_rf(dir) }"
```